# How to build docker images on AWS EC2 Windows Server instance?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, teamcity, docker-compose, hyper-v

We use Team City to build C# applications on a Windows server in AWS EC2.

Now there is a requirement to build Docker containers using the same system. The build steps have been tested locally and are able to produce a docker image.

Docker is not installing correctly on the server which leads to the builds failing.

Docker Edge supports Windows Server but fails on EC2 due to Hyper-V not functioning correctly.

Docker Toolbox also fails because VT-X/AMD-v are not enabled.

Is there any way to build docker images on an AWS EC2 Windows Server instance?